# Why didn't Dr. Liet-Kynes answer Paul's question?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

At the old ecological testing station in *Dune* (2021), Paul asks the female planetologist and imperial judge, Dr. Liet-Kynes:

> Paul: Who are you to the Fremen?

But she laughs and doesn't respond to the question.

Why didn't she answer Paul's question?

Comment: If you want us to answer exclusively from the 2021 film then it's not explicit. The book and previous adaptations hold the answer. Does this count as "future works"?

Comment: If you want us to answer exclusively from the 2021 film - YES

Comment: "*From that instant, Kynes had but to point, saying “Go there.” Entire Fremen tribes went. Men died, women died, children died. But they went.*" - So Kynes (senior and latterly junior) is basically the planetary leader of several tens of millions of Fremen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do not know why Dr. Kynes did not answer the male noble Paul. The 2021 film *Dune* does not make it clear.

That said, the Fremen are colonized by and insurgent against the empire. A Fremen, Fremen-sympathetic, or part-Fremen ecologist working directly for the Emperor would presumably need to walk a fine line, and we see Dr. Kynes being somewhat cagey throughout the film (coming most clean when confronted by Duncan after the Harkonnen attack). That she is still cagey when talking to someone the Emperor expected to be dead already is perhaps not surprising.